# Nginx url redirect for the site homepage

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

I just want to redirect my url

`https://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com`

Just this single link

How can I do that in nginx in the vhosts file .

I don't have any idea about how it works as I am new to nginx .
Any help is appreciated .

Comment: do you have a valid ssl certificate? because if you don't the redirection won't work even if you configure the redirection correctly, it would show the certificate warning first

Comment: Yes the certificate is valid . just dont know where to place the redirect rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said this is dependent on you having your functioning certificate

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  # add ssl settings here
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 http://www.example.com;
}
```

EDIT: only redirecting only the root URL

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  # add ssl settings
  location = / {
    return 301 http://www.example.com;
  }
}
```

Comment: But this will return http for all https request right ?

Comment: I have something like this at the end of file

server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name mysite.com;
   ssl_certificate /path/to/my/cert.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/key;
   return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;
}

Comment: do you want to redirect only the root URL ?

Comment: I tried doing this 

server { listen 80; listen 443 ssl; server_name mysite.com; ssl_certificate /path/to/my/cert.crt; ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/key; 
location / { rewrite https://www.mysite.com http://www.mysite.com permanent;}
return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri; }

Comment: I did this . Its still not working . Any other idea ?

server { listen 80; listen 443 ssl; server_name mysite.com; ssl_certificate /path/to/my/cert.crt; ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/key; location = / {
    return 301 http://www.example.com;
  }
 return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri; }